# Issue with perspective webkit transform and position absolute

Tags: css, webkit, absolute, css-transforms

Here is the html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```
.row {
    width: 173px;
    height: 38px;
    position: absolute;
}

.row div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #51565b;
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 173px ) rotateY( -20deg ) translate(-33px, 2px);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
}

ul {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 26px;
    top: 11px;
    z-index:10
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w3Wa4/

As you can see, i have a div with a perspective transformation, and i want to display a simple list above that, but half of the list is behind the div.

So it looks like this:

[image]

I tried to use z-index but its not working. Any idea?

Comment: In which browser? Because the jsFiddle looks vastly different in my Chrome than your image.

Comment: The screenshot was from Safari, i can see that Chrome looks different, but the issue is the same, you can only click on the first 3 dots, the rest of them are "hidden"